# before() and beforeAll() hooks are not getting recognised in WebdriverIO-Mocha framework having Jest as assertion library

Tags: mocha.js, jestjs, webdriver-io

before() and beforeAll() are not getting recognised in WebdriverIO-Mocha framework having Jest as assertion library.

For a ReactNative project we're building UI Automation using webdriver.IO+mocha. As its ReactNative, so main project code-base already has a extensive Jest library in built in the project.

Dependencies:

```
"jest": "23.6.0",
"jest-junit": "^5.2.0",
"jest-matchers": "^20.0.3",
"jest-transform-stub": "^1.0.0",
"wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.6.4",
"wdio-screenshots-cleanup-service": "0.0.7",
"wdio-spec-reporter": "^0.1.4",
"wdio-visual-regression-service": "^0.9.0",
"webdriverio": "^4.12.0"
```

[image]

I am getting error:

> ERROR: beforeAll is not defined

Also, unable to use Mocha's before() function at the same time.
Surprisingly editor is recognising beforeEach()

how to solve this issue, so that I can start using hooks like - before(), beforeAll() etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the Jest style hooks, but you're still running it through Mocha.

Use `before`, `beforeEach`, `afterEach` and `after` (the Mocha style ones).

You can still use Jest for your assertions (assuming you load them in correctly), but you can't use their style of hooks.

Comment: Thanks for your timely response. Also Kindly advise - what issues/ side-effects we may have as we need to use Async/Await due to `describe` and `it` blocks are infact from interfering Jest framework from the parent project.?